# Explain 3d transformation matrix...

Tags: matrices, 3d

In programming language like [CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function#matrix3d()), there are [matrices](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/matrix3d). Though I don't know matrix or matrix3d. I have tried to learn it again and again for one year. And have not been successful :( However, I do know now that matrices are added, multiplied, etc. I just don't know what each value among $16$ values mean. So, could someone please explain to me how this matrix is supposed to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't need to understand the meaning of each one of the 16 matrix elements. You have to think in a matrix as a mathematical abstraction that represents some transformation, like a rotation, a translation, a scale or a perspective. When you multiply this matrix by a point, you get the transformed point.
For example, if you have a matrix representing a rotation around an axis and you multiply this matrix by a point, you get the point rotated around this axis.

So, you have to understand that a matrix is just a convenient way of expressing a transformation and that you can apply this transformation to a point just by multiplying.

Now, why do we need 2x2, 3x3 or 4x4 matrices?. Basically it is related with the fact of if we are working in 2d or 3d. For example, to express transformation in 2d we just need a 2x2 matrix, to express rotation or scaling in 3d we need a 3x3 matrix and to express translation or perspective calculations in 3d we need a 4x4 matrix.

The way of constructing a matrix is just calculating matrices for single transformations and multiplying together to get the matrix representing the total transformation. Each individual transformation (matrix) can be constructed as is indicated in the link you have provided in your question.

**EDIT:**

If you look at the description for the RotateX(a) function, you will se that they specify the matrix form for this transformation:

1   0   0   0
0   cos(a)  sin(a)  0
0   -sin(a) cos(a)  0
0   0   0   1

And the same for the [`RotateY(b)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/rotateY) function:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
 \cos(b) & 0 & \sin(b) & 0 \\ 
      0  & 1 &      0  & 0 \\ 
-\sin(b) & 0 & \cos(b) & 0 \\ 
      0  & 0 &      0  & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

So if you want to apply a combined transformation, use matrix3d( ...) with the matrix resulting of multiplying the ones above.

In general it is difficult to say the meaning of each one of the parameters in matrix3d. As this matrix is representing combined transformation, each element of the matrix is the result the several multiplications and additions as a result of the matrices multiplication.

Thus, you cannot expect to build this matrix just by knowing the meaning of each one of its parameters.

Comment: at that site it doesn't describe matrix3d... again i am clueless how or where information is stored in matrix about scale rotation translation skewing and perspective.

Comment: Yes, in that site you have information about matrix3d. They describe the order of the arguments. After this explanation you can find how to build the matrix for each transformation. For example, if you look at the explanation of rotate(), you'll find a table where specifies the value for each component of the matrix in terms of the rotation angle.

Comment: no rotate is separate..i can't find what each variable means. matrix3d describes a new function that is a combination of all other functions on that page. But since no one understand that, so most ppl use a sperate transformation functions like rotateY..

Comment: If you want to apply some single transformation like rotateX or rotateY then you must use these functions directly. But what if you want to apply both transformations (rotateX and rotateY) at the same time?. In that case you need to use the general form of matrix3d. The values of the arguments are the values of the matrix obtained by multiplying the matrix in rotateX and the matrix in rotateY. So, matrix3d is a special function provided in order to apply combination of transformations or custom transformations.

Comment: i know matrix3d combines all transformation, i just want to know what represents what in the parameters of this function. You said values are.. matrix..X x matrix..Y but rotateX/y accept radians not matrix. So where are you getting the matrixX x matrixY = matrix3d.

Comment: just look at the edit in my original answer

Comment: ok, so it each variable itself doesn't represent unique transformation than what does it represent and how do you build a matrix. Given lets say you want to do distort, translate, rotate, and skew.

Comment: If you want to translate, rotate and skew, you have to go to the corresponding description of each function. In the description you will find the matrix form for each function. Write down the matrix of each function. Once you have all the matrices, you have to multiply all of them. The resulting matrix is what you have to indicate as argument in matrix3d(...) function. Please, note that order is important. I mean, it is not the same translate, rotate and skew that skew, rotate and translate. Matrix multiplication is not commutative.

Comment: yes now we are talking, i know order is important found out the hard way.

Comment: I improved a bit.  Please improve the rest

Answer (score 1):

The best source of thuth is source code.

1. [MapPointInternal 2d and 3d](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/main/ui/gfx/geometry/transform.cc#L948-L980).
2. [Matrix 4x4](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/main/ui/gfx/geometry/matrix44.h#L17-L35)

Source vector from point 2D is `[x, y, 1]` where 3-rd coordinate is perspective. Source vector from point 3D is `[x, y, z, 1]` where 4-th coordinate is perspective.

You are multiplying source vector by matrix. Result point can be received from result vector by dividing each coordinate by last coordinate (perspective) if it is not zero.

```
[x1, y1, 1] * matrix => [x2, y2, p2] => [x2 / p2, y2 / p2].
[x1, y1, z1, 1] * matrix => [x2, y2, z2, p2] => [x2 / p2, y2 / p2, z2 / p2].
```

You can also find many helpers that will describe how to create `scale`, `skew`, etc in the same geometry folder.